# Coding state machine table (Verilog HDL)

Tags: verilog

[image]

This is a practice problem, that I think is the correct approach. I got stuck in finding out what to put for when x = 0. I'm a verilog hdl novice, therefore unsure if this is a valid state machine module. Please point out any mistakes.

```
Module SM(input x, clk, output z)
 reg[1:0] s, next_s;
 always @(posedge clk)
  s <= next_s;
 always @(x,s) begin
  if (x == 1)begin
   next_s <= s + 1'b1;
  else 
   next_s <= ?????
  end
 end 

 assign z = ~{s[0],s[1]};
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of notes:

1. Use `always@ (*)` for combinational logic, rather than specifying the sensitivity list manually.
2. We use non-blocking assignments (`<=`) in sequential (edge-sensitive) blocks, but blocking assignments (`=`) in combinational blocks.
3. Your assignment to `z` is incorrect (you  probably want something like `s[1] == s[0]`)
4. It looks to me like the state decrements when `x==1`, and increments when `x==0`, while you increment in the `x==1` case, and don't have anything for the `x==0`.

Otherwise, it looks OK!